# Datepicker Dialog Validation...!

Tags: android, validation, datepicker

I create app for calculate AGE.
This app works fine, but now I want to put Validation in datepicker Dialog.
when user set date through datepicker dialog, 
then **USER CAN NOT SET BIRTHDATE GREATERTHAN CURRENT DATE...**

what should I do?
here is my code...
AgeCalculator.java

```
package com.example.agecalculator;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AgeCalculator extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView currentDate, birthDate, ageDisplay;
    AgeCalculation age = null;
    static final int DATE_START_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private int startYear = 2015;
    private int startMonth = 0;
    private int startDay = 8;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        age = new AgeCalculation();
        currentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSysDate);
        currentDate.setText(age.getCurrentDate());
        birthDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBirthDate);
        birthDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        ageDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
        Calendar valid = Calendar.getInstance();
        int validYear = valid.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int validMonth = valid.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int validDay = valid.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_START_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, startYear,
                    startMonth, startDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            startYear = selectedYear;
            startMonth = selectedMonth;
            startDay = selectedDay;
            age.setDateOfBirth(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
            birthDate.setText(selectedDay + "-" + (startMonth + 1) + "-"
                    + startYear);
            calculateAge();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.txtBirthDate:
            showDialog(DATE_START_DIALOG_ID);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private void calculateAge() {
        age.calcualteYear();
        age.calcualteMonth();
        age.calcualteDay();

        ageDisplay.setText(age.getResult());
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

AgeCalculation.java

```
package com.example.agecalculator;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AgeCalculation {
    private Calendar end;
    private Calendar start;
    private int endYear;
    private int endMonth;
    private int endDay;
    private int startYear;
    private int startMonth;
    private int startDay;
    private int calYear;
    private int calMonth;
    private int calDay;

    public String getCurrentDate() {
        end = Calendar.getInstance();
        endYear = end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        endMonth = end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        endMonth++;
        endDay = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return endDay + "-" + endMonth + "-" + endYear;

    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay) {
        startYear = sYear;
        startMonth = sMonth;
        startMonth++;
        startDay = sDay;

        if (sYear > endYear) {

        }

    }

    public void calcualteYear() {
        calYear = endYear - startYear;

    }

    public void calcualteMonth() {
        if (endMonth >= startMonth) {
            calMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
        } else {
            calMonth = endMonth - startMonth;
            calMonth = 12 + calMonth;
            calYear--;
        }

    }

    public void calcualteDay() {

        if (endDay >= startDay) {
            calDay = endDay - startDay;
        } else {
            calDay = endDay - startDay;
            calDay = 30 + calDay;
            if (calMonth == 0) {
                calMonth = 11;
                calYear--;
            } else {
                calMonth--;
            }

        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return "Day: " + calDay + "\n" + "Month:" + calMonth + "\n" + "Year:"
                + calYear;
    }

    public long getSeconde() {
        start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.set(Calendar.YEAR, startYear);
        start.set(Calendar.MONTH, startMonth);
        start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, startDay);
        start.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
        start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
        start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 60);
        long now = end.getTimeInMillis();
        long old = start.getTimeInMillis();
        long diff = old - now;
        return diff / 1000;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

I use below code in my application for set validation in `DataPicker` `Dialog`.

```
// Global declaration

    Calendar preferDate1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    Calendar preferDate2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    private int year, month, day;


    // here preferredDate1 and preferredDate2 are textview
    preferredDate1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, prefferedDate1Picker, preferDate1
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), preferDate1.get(Calendar.MONTH), preferDate1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    dp.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    dp.show();
                }
            });

    private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener prefferedDate1Picker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                preferDate1 = new GregorianCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
                preferredDate2.setText("");
                preferredDate1.setText((selectedDay < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf(selectedDay) : String.valueOf(selectedDay)) + "/"
                        + (selectedMonth + 1 < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)) : String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)))
                        + "/" + selectedYear);

            }
        };


// This will set date based on preferredDate1
// change here according to your need. If you want to add or remove one month then set based on data. In this I add one day in second data picker.
preferredDate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerDialog dp2 = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, prefferedDate2Picker, preferDate2
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), preferDate2.get(Calendar.MONTH), preferDate2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    long mili = preferDate1.getTimeInMillis() + 86400000L;
                    dp2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mili);
                    dp2.show();

            }
        });

        private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener prefferedDate2Picker = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            preferDate2 = new GregorianCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay+1);
            preferredDate2.setText((selectedDay < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf(selectedDay) : String.valueOf(selectedDay)) + "/"
                    + (selectedMonth + 1 < 10 ? "0" + String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)) : String.valueOf((selectedMonth + 1)))
                    + "/" + selectedYear);

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to disable the selection of the item .

Create your own subclass of ArrayAdapter where you override areAllItemsEnabled() to return false and isEnabled() to return true or false as needed.